# fetching all the events a user has been invited to with Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to retrieve user's events via "...me/events".
as written in the documentation the response includes only events which the user respond to.
is there any way getting also the events the user was invited to and has not respond?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I made it with Facebook FQL:

```
var eventsQuery = "{'eventslist':\'SELECT eid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() AND start_time > " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + " ORDER BY start_time','eventsdetails':'SELECT eid, name, description, location, venue, creator, pic_square, start_time, end_time FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM #eventslist) ORDER BY start_time'}";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner/creator of the event then you can query the `invited` connection of the even object. Otherwise there is no way of retrieving that data.

Taken from the [Graph API Event reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#invited)

```
You can read the list of invitees for an event by issuing an HTTP GET to /EVENT_ID/invited:
https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/invited
```